# Bootstrap vertical tabbing in multi column grid

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a two-columns form using Twitter Bootstrap 3 grid system. Each column is composed by a label and a control. So actually, each "row" is 4 columns of span3 each (a label, a control, a label, a control).  This is working great, but I have the problem that when I tab, it goes from left to right tabbing horizontally. But I want to scroll vertically, that means, a tab goes all down until that column is finished, and then second column...

I read about `tabindex` that. But I was wondering if I could do something more automatic...I mean, I would like to render the HTML so that the default tab order is the one I want. That means I should render left column first, then second column. And maybe some CSS magic so that the second column is not below the first one but on the right... any idea if this is possible or how?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Hey I just thought I would remind you to go back through your previous questions and `mark` an answer as `accepted` if it answered your question.  This can be done by clicking on the `check mark` just to the left of the question.

Comment: Set the tabindex of all the inputs in the first column to 1, then 2 for the second column and so on. If you don't want to do it in your markup you could writa a simple jquery script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for `tabindex` you can set the tab index on your elements like the following:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
```

So you need to adjust the tab index for your elements so that the first column has `tabindex="1"`,`tabindex="2"` etc..

jQuery - (You may need to adjust the function so that it handles your `bootstrap` columns correctly.)

```
var tabindex = 1;
$('input,select').each(function() {
  if (this.type != "hidden") {
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
    tabindex++;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I read about that. But I was wondering if I could do something more automatic...I mean, I would like to render the HTML so that the default tab order is the one I want. That means I should render left column first, then second column. And maybe some CSS magic so that the second column is not below the first one but on the right...

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck Not sure about that.. You can set the tab index for all the input elements using jQuery though.

Comment: Thanks. This actually solved my problem. What I did is that I surrounded each left part in a div with certain ID and each right part with another ID. Then with a script similar to yours I started from 1 to only those inputs for the div #leftColumn. Then I did the same but starting with 100 and for the inputs for the div #rightColumn. Thanks!